# How to use the objectGUID get a DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, active-directory, guid, directoryservices, directoryentry

I know ,we can get a DirectoryEntry like this:

```
string conPath = "LDAP://10.0.0.6/DC=wds,DC=gaga,DC=com";
string conUser = "administrator";
string conPwd = "Iampassword";
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(conPath, conUser, conPwd, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

and we can change a user's password like this:

```
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
deSearch.Filter = String.Format("sAMAccountName={0}", "xumai");
SearchResultCollection results = deSearch.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult objResult in results)
{
    DirectoryEntry obj = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
    obj.Invoke("setPassword", new object[] { "Welcome99" });
    obj.CommitChanges();
}
```

if use

```
string x = obj.Guid.ToString();;
```

we can get the user's objectGUID  "0b118130-2a6f-48d0-9b66-c12a0c71d892"

how can i change it is password base this objectGUID ?

how to search the user base this objectGUID form "LDAP://10.0.0.6/DC=wds,DC=gaga,DC=com"?

is there any way filter it ?  etc strFilter = "(&(objectGUID=0b118130-2a6f-48d0-9b66-c12a0c71d892))";

hope for your help

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without changing you code you've got [multiple way to bind to Active-Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772152%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Here are two others ways :

The first one [use GUID to bind to an object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
string conPath = "LDAP://10.0.0.6/<GUID=0b118130-2a6f-48d0-9b66-c12a0c71d892>";
```

The second one [use SID to bind to an object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675562%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
string conPath = "LDAP://10.0.0.6/<SID=S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXX>";
```

Using [security Principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) you can do it like that :

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adPrincipalContext, IdentityType.DistinguishedName,"CN=User1Acct,OU=TechWriters,DC=wds,DC=gaga,DC=com");
```

or

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adPrincipalContext, IdentityType.Guid,"0b118130-2a6f-48d0-9b66-c12a0c71d892");
```

Answer (score 0):

If .NET 3.5 is an option, you should start using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. It is a whole new world. Here's is the code to find a user by the GUID:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
                                                  "LDAP://10.0.0.6", 
                                                  "DC=wds,DC=gaga,DC=com", 
                                                  "administrator", 
                                                  "Iampassword"))
{
    string theGuid = "0b118130-2a6f-48d0-9b66-c12a0c71d892";
    UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Guid, theGuid);
}
```

The same template would be easily adapted to other object types.

Comment: Oh thank you ,but i need to change the  "LDAP://10.0.0.6/"  to "10.0.0.6" and it works well .
and how to do this if the GUID is a OU's ?
i readed the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace, and there is no one class for OU .

Comment: Oops, copy and paste typo. Fixed that. I'll post an update for OU soon