# ASP.NET Active Directory C# field specification

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, active-directory

We've got an active directory here. provided the unique user id of the user, I need to access the organization->manager->name attribute related to that userid. Basically this will be used to send an approval form to the manager of the person submitting request.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code :

```
/* Retreiving object from SID  
  */  
string SidLDAPURLForm = "LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/<SID={0}>";  
System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sidToFind = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-21-3115856885-816991240-3296679909-1106");  

/*
System.Security.Principal.NTAccount user = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("SomeUsername");
System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sidToFind = user.Translate(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)
*/

DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format(SidLDAPURLForm, sidToFind.Value));  
string managerDn = userEntry.Properties["manager"].Value.ToString();
```

But you can also find [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651586/how-to-use-the-objectguid-get-a-directoryentry/6658928#6658928) other ways to seach bind to Active-directory.

Comment: this seems to be what I need to do, but sorry not too sure about the literal values..anyway you could clarify that?

Comment: I Edit to add into comment the way for recovering SID from name.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do in your concrete case... the `UserPrincipal` has an `EmployeeId` property - is that what you want to search for?

Comment: not it isn't really. There are two unique id's here one is numbers and the other is alphanumeric. I need the latter one. So basically an ID like hah2jah1 will be entered, and each employee has a head of division, so I need to find that head based on ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) class to read out the appropriate property of the user object. The constructor of `DirectoryEntry` requires that you have an LDAP path to the user. Getting the LDAP path can often be tricky though as IIS prefers handing over the SAM account name only. If you provide more details of what the user id you have looks like it is easier to point you in the right direction.

To do this the account which runs the ASP.NET application needs read access to the AD, which probably doesn't have by default. Changing the application pool to run under "NetworkService" is the easiest way if the web server belongs to the AD. The ASP.NET app will then use the MACHINE$ account of the server to access the AD.